# Pixel labelled image is must for semantic segmentation using deep learning in matlab?

Tags: deep-learning, matlab, semantic-segmentation

I have large set of CT images containing lung regions. But I don't have corrosponding pixel labelled images. So how I could do semantic segmentation using DL in matlab. Like a test program I created 6 pixel labelled images using image Labeler. But it's not practical. I have thousands of such images. Could someone help me with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the bounding boxes then you can use MaskRCNN and it will be able to give you those segmentations.

If you don't, look at [unsupervised segmentation](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.09990). Also, you need something as an output if you want to try out supervised learning.